# What is the use of MIT in swagger2.0 based document

Tags: documentation, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have documented the APIs a product into swagger based document, I already have searched but not found any satisfactory solution about the use of MIT in the document.

Any guide will be highly appreciated.

This is MIT attribute link:

license:
name: MIT
url: 'http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'

Comment: Welcome, what do you mean by "the use of MIT in the document"?

Comment: @albert  i have added MIT attribute in post kindly have a look.

Comment: So you want to license your documentation or software under the MIT license. There will be enough examples around. I cannot give any advise, I'm not schooled in law.

Comment: Check out these discussions in the OpenAPI Specification repository: [Clarification on the purpose of the API license?](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/726), [Provide additional detail in the documentation regarding the differences in Licensing vs. Terms of Service](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1672)

Comment: Informative, thanks @Helen